# Python OOP function

Tags: python, class, oop, call

I need to write a Class with functions which would have a fuctionality

```
x = np.linspace(-10., 10., num=100)
sig = Sigmoid()(x)
sig_prime = Sigmoid().prime(x)
```

That's the template:

```
class Sigmoid:
    def __call__(self, z):
        """
        Compute the sigmoid of z
        Arguments:
        z -- scalar or numpy array of any size.
        Return:
        sigmoid(z)
        """
        sigmoid = 1/np.exp(-z)
        return sigmoid
    
    def prime(self, z):
        """
        Compute the derivative of sigmoid of z
        Arguments:
        z -- scalar or numpy array of any size.
        Return:
        Sigmoid prime
        """
        ###return sigmoid * (1 - sigmoid)
```

Please, can you help me to write the function def prime(self, z)? Because I have no idea how I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
def prime(self, z):
  s = 1/np.exp(-z)
  ds = s*(1-s)
  return ds
```

Found it [here](https://pylessons.com/Logistic-Regression-part1/).

Comment: thanks a lot, I thought I should somehow use the function "__call__"  Thank you so much!